# OpenSSL PKI function crashes on 32-bit Solaris 10

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, pki

I have a small test program (source is [here](http://pastebin.com/X9XcwEqJ)) that uses OpenSSL 1.0.2j to do a very simple PKI encrypt / decrypt. This program works on Windows, Linux, and Solaris (64-bit) but fails if I run a 32-bit version on Solaris 10. Solaris 11 is fine.

If I use `./config -kPIC -m32 -xarch=sparc` to build OpenSSL, I get a crash in bn_mul_mont_t4_32 (called within RSA_public_encrypt). I added `no-asm` and it no longer crashes but I get this error output:

```
OSSL error
4275158204:error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:rsa_pk1.c:272:

End OSSL error
decrypt failed
```

I also tried adding `-d` to the config line and then the program *succeeds* though is very verbose.

Could this be a bug in OpenSSL, or am I configuring it incorrectly, or is there a bug in my code? I posted this same question to both the openssl-users and openssl-dev mailing lists with no response so I'm hoping someone here recognizes the problem.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining the problem with this question?

Comment: Just a guess about the downvote... No code, no data, and no mcve. I think it could either way. I've worked OpenSSL problems long enough to know sometimes a high level discussion is useful or helpful. I've also had my share of Solaris problems, even on Intel machines. Does configuring with no-asm make a difference? Does `-xarch=sparc` and/or `-m32` make a difference? Did you us the same `CFLAGS` for everything (program and library)? Does `ldd` show you are linking to the library you expect?

Comment: There's a link to the code which is on pastebin (It's not huge but I thought it was too big to post here). No data is needed. Compile the code and you have a mcve (though I guess I could have added a makefile). As I said in the question, adding no-asm makes the crash go away but the encryption still fails. I will try removing `-xarch` and `-m32` but those are supposed to tell config to build a 32-bit library rather than 64-bit.

Comment: Checkout the last four or five commits. Especially dca2e0ee17..a54aba5313. They had a bug in their Montgomery Multiplier for some platforms, and the fix was checked in over the last couple of days. Maybe you should clone OpenSSL, checkout the 1.0.2 branch, and then re-run the experiment. Pain in the butt, but it might explain the issue.

Comment: There are three changes in that range. One is specific to Intel, one to PPC, and the other is a change to a test file, so none should affect my case directly. However it is suspicious that they found a bug in the Montgomery multiplication routines which is exactly where my crash is happening. Perhaps I need to fix it myself - ah, the joys of open source. Thanks @jww

Comment: Yeah, its suspicious. Do you have Valgrind under Sparc? I know its available on Intel machines, and I use it frequently for testing.

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not doing FOSS development, I'm just an OpenSSL user.